# Sending funds from a Segwit address to a non segwit

Tags: bitcoin-core, segregated-witness

I just generated a Electrum wallet with the Segwit option on. I wonder what happens if I try to transfer **SegWit -> Non-SegWit** or **Non-SegWit -> SegWit**: Will the funds be confirmed and get transfered or will it be lost forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what happens if I try to transfer SegWit -> Non-SegWit or Non-SegWit -> SegWit

As long as you are using software that supports doing so, this is perfectly possible and fine to do.

> Will the funds be confirmed and get transfered or will it be lost forever?

Bitcoin can never be lost forever because of an unconfirmed transaction. For an unconfirmed transaction, the bitcoin do not move from their starting address until they are confirmed in a block. Eventually a transaction may be confirmed, or the network's nodes will remove the old unconfirmed transaction from their mempool's, and you will be able to spend the coins again. There are a few of ways to push unconfirmed transactions through, like replace-by-fee (RBF) or child-pays-for-parent (CPFP).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm asking this because I'm afraid to start using these Segwit wallets and not being able to transfer money from, for example, the Exchange wallet to my personal wallet. Being that said, how can I be sure that the Exchange wallet supports Segwit?

Comment: *'The exchange supporting segwit'* would generally refer to the exchange allowing customers to deposit funds into a segwit address controlled by the exchange. The exchange does not need to explicitly support segwit in order to send an outgoing tx to a segwit address. You do not need to worry in that regard.